# Replace incorrectly formatted values in a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, type-conversion

I am importing an Excel spreadsheet as a dataframe using pandas. The spreadsheet is manually maintained and contains several data entry errors, the most common of which is integers formatted as strings with leading non-breaking spaces ('\xa0'). The spreadsheet is updated regularly, so where and when these pesky inconsistencies pop up is totally unpredictable.

Basically, I am trying to find a clean way to find and re-format these values. As they are mainly restricted to one column, I have tried several versions of this:

```
for entry in df.loc[:, 'col']:
    if type(row) == str:
        row = row.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
```

If I add a `print(row)` call inside the `for` loop, it prints exactly what I expect, i.e., '   1187383' becomes '1187383'. However, outside of the `for` loop, the value is not being replaced. Once the loop executes, calling `.loc` returns the unchanged entry ('  1187383').

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I've now invested about a day trying to find the solution. Any help is appreciated! And please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: all of them are numbers?

Comment: Yes, all numbers.

Comment: `df.replace('[^0-9]','',regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric)` will this work?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, that didn't remove the space.

Comment: did you do `df = df.replace('...`  because it should remove the spaces atleast

Comment: I did try df.replace, passing a dictionary, and got an "infinite loop" of exceptions. It froze my IDLE. :) I also have tried `map` and `apply`, which technically I believe could work if I convert all values in the column to `str` on import and then back to `int` for analysis purposes - however, and this wasn't part of my original question, but there are also numbers in this Excel spreadsheet which are formatted as dates within the column, so converting all to `str` seems messy in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend trying [Bharath Shetty's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566665/python-3-6-replace-incorrectly-formatted-values-in-a-dataframe#comment80087393_46566665), but with a slight improvement:

```
s = df['col'].astype(str).str.replace('[^0-9.]', '')
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! And, as suspected, I did miss something obvious. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: I too wanted to post an answer but no data makes me bit scared to put one.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Sometimes you gotta take the leap of faith.

Comment: I will from now on. :)